server not receiving cookies from browser (localhost/127.0.0.1) express.js
I am having a problem with cookies, they are created, they are sent to browser, browser sent the cookies back, but req.cookies are undefined in server...
What am i doing wrong?
Thanks you for the help.
I have tried having all the enviroment in localhost and also in 127.0.0.1, the outcome is exactly the same, cookies are writen in browser and sent back, but req.cookies are undefined in both cases.
header request

Accept:
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:
es-ES,es;q=0.9
Cache-Control:
max-age=0
Connection:
keep-alive
Cookie:
sessionId=example
Host:
127.0.0.1:3000
If-None-Match:
W/"7-PEnZzDwMg0IaHPuSHN1Ko13Bulw"
Sec-Ch-Ua:
"Not A(Brand";v="99", "Opera GX";v="107", "Chromium";v="121"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile:
?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform:
"Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest:
document
Sec-Fetch-Mode:
navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site:
none
Sec-Fetch-User:
?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:
1
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/107.0.0.0

/index.ts  

import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'; 
[...] 
app.use(cookieParser('' + process.env.COOKIE_SECRET)); 
[...] 
app.use('/', indexRouter)

/routes/index.ts

import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.cookies); // always undefined
    res.cookie("sessionId", "example");
    res.send("running");
});

export default router;


Finally what i have done is to manually read the cookie from the headers directly. As i suspect that the problem is caused by localhost, i ahve created a middleware which will use cookie-parser as first option, and if it doesn't work, i read and parse manually the cookie from the headers. Here is the code:
export function cookieReader(req: any): { [key: string]: string } | undefined {
    if (req.cookies !== undefined) {
        return req.cookies;
    }
    if (req.headers.cookie !== undefined) {
        let cookie: any = {};
        req.headers.cookie.split(/\W*\;\W*/g).forEach((x: any) => {
            const kv = x.split(/\W*\=\W*/g);
            cookie[kv[0]] = decodeURIComponent(kv[1]);
        });
        return cookie;
    }
    return undefined;
}

